# python regex match to find multi-matching on multi line

Tags: python, regex

I spend three days now on writing regular expression for matching multi-string on multiline. 
I have file has text as follow:

```
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 futex(0x7f8087eb18, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid   621] 23:13:36 futex(0x7f80855410, FUTEX_WAIT, 1041, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
[pid   621] 23:13:36 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 EAGAIN (Try again)
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 munmap(0x7f80200000, 8192 <unfinished ...>
--> [pid   621] 23:13:36 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/task", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 <... munmap resumed> ) = 0
[pid   621] 23:13:36 <... openat resumed> ) = 13
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 madvise(0x7f76a7b000, 20480, MADV_DONTNEED <unfinished ...>
 --> [pid   621] 23:13:36 hammad(13, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, 24 )
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 madvise(0x7f76a7b000, 20480, MADV_DONTNEED <unfinished ...>
[pid   621] 23:13:36 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 futex(0x7f80855410, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid   621] 23:13:36 futex(0x7f8087eb18, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
[pid   621] 23:13:36 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 futex(0x7f8087eb18, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid   621] 23:13:36 futex(0x7f80855410, FUTEX_WAIT, 1041, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 20242] 23:13:36 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
```

I added "-->" For clarity on above for which string I looked for. however, I need to found if there is pattern where     "openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/task", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC "  is followed by  hammad(13, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, 24 ). it can be there ae multi-line between them but the important things there are "openat" followed by "hammad" functions.

I have a lot of files with different texts but I want to use the same pattern for matching. 
Here is my code:

```
text = open('textfile.txt').read()


if re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z\s.-]*openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/task", 
 O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>([a-zA-Z0-9|\s|.])*hammad(13, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, 24 )", text):

    print 'found a match!'
else:
    print 'no match'
```

Can anyone help me to fix my code? 
thanks

Comment: What defines the boundary? ie, `hammad` can be anywhere following`openat`? Do those two define a block of text? Is there something in between that would make it not a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/^.*openat(?:[\s\S]*)^.*hammad.*/gm
```

The key elements are:

1. The `m` flag for multiline;
2. Knowing that `.*` matches any horizontal character but does not match a newline (unless you use the `s` flag);
3. `[\s\S]*` matches any character including a newline.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7iba7P/2/)

Python demo:

```
>>> re.findall(r"^.*openat(?:[\s\S]*)^.*hammad.*", txt, re.M)
['--> [pid   621] 23:13:36 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/task", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>\n[pid 20242] 23:13:36 <... munmap resumed> ) = 0\n[pid   621] 23:13:36 <... openat resumed> ) = 13\n[pid 20242] 23:13:36 madvise(0x7f76a7b000, 20480, MADV_DONTNEED <unfinished ...>\n --> [pid   621] 23:13:36 hammad(13, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, 24 )']
```

If you want to add literal qualifying characters after `hammad` just remember to escape any regex meta characters.

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks, dawg. I was though is much complicated. Thank for simplifying it.

Comment: what about if I want to match even the string that inside the parentheses. I found one of my text file has two of hammad(13, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, 24 ) and hammad(12, FUTEX_idel, 1, 24 ). I need just to match the first one which is   hammad(13, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, 24 )

Comment: You can add that literal string to the regex and just remember to escape the literal parenthesis :`\(` or `\)`.

Comment: If this is useful, please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, an answer like @dawg had above is clearly much simpler in terms of the regex.

With that said, as a general Python and Regex learning opportunity, there are a few things in your example that stood out as causing the error.

1. You have double quotes " in your pattern, but also as the character telling python to start the string. So you can either escape those \" or use a different starting character for the string representation in Python. Either single quote ' or triple quotes """ would work in this case.
2. You are using several regex metacharacters in your pattern. Things like [ ( | have special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape those as well, by leading them with \, so | becomes \| if you want it to be used literally instead of the special regex meaning.

@dawg implicitely fixed all these things by writing a more concise regex without these problems, but I think that's the root of your issue you posted.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Mego your tips is very helpful for me. I think my big mistake was using "" without escape \". I still have a lot to do with Regex on python :)